Run only exactly one instance of a program on Wayland
I use terminator as my terminal app. To avoid pollution with too many open terminals, I only ever want to use a single instance of terminator. So far I achieved this with this solution. Here, wmctrl -xa MyApp || MyApp is used to check if the app is already running. It will either bring the running instance to the foreground or launch it.
This solution is specific to X11. With wayland becoming the default window manager on Ubuntu soon, how can a similar behaviour be achieved on Wayland?


Basic build-in solution: On the Ubuntu Dock, pin your terminal on a fixed position on the dock. By default, you can now run - if the application is not running yet - or raise an existing window by hitting Super+Number where number is the order of the icon on the dock. This shortcut key can be rebound using dconf-editor by editing the values for org.gnome.shell.keybindings switch-to-application-#.
Solution on steroids: Gnome-shell extension Run or raise by e2rd. With this excellent Gnome Shell extension (which I use for several years), you can implement as many shortcut keys as you want that implement run or raise behavior. It is actually a general alternative keyboard shortcut daemon: you can move all your custom keybindings conveniently out into a single, editable text file.

